# Dlib - Object tracking over several shots

Tags: python, opencv, dlib

I am trying to find the start + end time of a person appears in a video.
My current approach is to find the person using face detection, and then track his face using dlib object tracking (i.e. if the person is turning around in the video, i can't know that he is still in the video using face recognition. Therefore i need both detection and tracking techniques).

The problem is that the object tracking still tracks after an object, even if there was a camera shot cut or scene changed.

So, I tried to initialize the tracking object every shot. But, it's not so easy to detect the shots. even with very high sensitivity, ffmpeg and http://mklab.iti.gr/project/video-shot-segm don't return all of the shot cuts.

So, it turns out that I need to compare the object rectangle of the previous frame, with the rectangle detected in the current frame.

Any idea of a function that can give me a "similarity score" between two rectangles in two frames?